# last column of multicols has excessive whitespace

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicol

The last column of a `multicols` has extra whitespace that is not needed (as visually the margin will do):

```
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{description}
\item[asdf] - fdasdf
\item[asdf] - fdasdf
\item[asdf] - fdasdf
\item[as42df] - fda432sdf
\item[as42df] - fda432sdf
\item[as42df] - fda432sdf
\item[59093] - 5324
\item[59093] - 5324
\item[59093] - 5324
\end{description}
\end{multicols}
```

The table will not look centered.

Basically I want to center the `multicols` visually (which means that the minimal bounding box (i.e., excluding whitespace) is centered).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest going with a more rigid structure then; something like a `tabular` would work fine:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
  \begin{description}
    \item[asdf] - fdasdf
    \item[asdf] - fdasdf
    \item[asdf] - fdasdf
    \item[as42df] - fda432sdf
    \item[as42df] - fda432sdf
    \item[as42df] - fda432sdf
    \item[59093] - 5324
    \item[59093] - 5324
    \item[59093] - 5324
  \end{description}
\end{multicols}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{l@{\quad}l@{\quad}l}
    \textbf{asdf} - fdasdf & \textbf{as42df} - fda432sdf & \textbf{59093} - 5324 \\[.7\normalbaselineskip]
    \textbf{asdf} - fdasdf & \textbf{as42df} - fda432sdf & \textbf{59093} - 5324 \\[.7\normalbaselineskip]
    \textbf{asdf} - fdasdf & \textbf{as42df} - fda432sdf & \textbf{59093} - 5324
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

You can fiddle around with the horizontal space between the columns (`\quad` in my MWE). Another option would be to use a `p`aragraph-style `p{<len>}` column type, which would allow for using `description`. The vertical lines on the side are from the [`showframe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) indicating the text block boundaries.

You don't mention the *requirement* to necessarily keep the `description` environment, nor being able to break across the page boundary.

---

Perhaps a less-attractive alternative would be to wrap `multicols` inside an `adjustwidth` environment (from [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage)) to modify the left & right margin temporarily. Not sure how much problems this might cause down the road though:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\usepackage{changepage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
  \begin{description}
    \item[asdf] - fdasdf
    \item[asdf] - fdasdf
    \item[asdf] - fdasdf
    \item[as42df] - fda432sdf
    \item[as42df] - fda432sdf
    \item[as42df] - fda432sdf
    \item[59093] - 5324
    \item[59093] - 5324
    \item[59093] - 5324
  \end{description}
\end{multicols}

\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{1cm}
  \begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{description}
      \item[asdf] - fdasdf
      \item[asdf] - fdasdf
      \item[asdf] - fdasdf
      \item[as42df] - fda432sdf
      \item[as42df] - fda432sdf
      \item[as42df] - fda432sdf
      \item[59093] - 5324
      \item[59093] - 5324
      \item[59093] - 5324
    \end{description}
  \end{multicols}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

Note that the margin adjustments do not take the environment contents into consideration. As such, disproportionate columns will cause a disproportionate layout and "centering adjustment."

Comment: The tabular doesn't break nicely into proper groups. If you want to add additional elements you have to change just about everything. The description list breaks over nicely and properly so that adding additional elements is very easy. The only issue is the extra whitespace. I used a description env because it suits my needs. It would be better to modify it to get rid of the extra whitespace than use something that is not appropriate.

Comment: You could use a `p`aragraph-style `p{<len>}` column to fix the width. This would allow column entries to break properly at the desired length.

Comment: Would using `minipage`s be an option?

Comment: well, I'd prefer some way to use description since I already have it all coded and it would seem rather simple to make it work. Couldn't I just temporarily increase the margins by some amount to trick it to center(approximately at least)?

Comment: @Uiy: I've added some discussion on `adjustwidth` (from [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage)) that allows for margin adjustments.

Answer (score 2):

The `multicols` environment will naturally center its columns with no excessive whitespace as you see.
The reason you experiencing this problem is your use of a list. You will need to redefine your list environment. Here is a MWE employing the plain vanilla `trivlist` environment, showing that the problem disappears. The rest is just filler text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{trivlist}
\item [test] this is something
\item [test] this is something
\end{trivlist}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

A package that you may find suitable is the `multienum`. Here is MWE using it with maths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\usepackage{multienum}
\renewcommand{\regularlisti}{\setcounter{multienumi}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\labelenumi}%
  {\addtocounter{multienumi}{1}\alph{multienumi})}}
\begin{document}
\begin{multienumerate}
\mitemxxx{\(x^2 + y^2 = 1\)}{\(a + b = c\)}{\(r-x = y+z\)}
\mitemxxx{\(f - y = z\)}{\(a - b = 2d\)}{\(r+x = 2y-3z\)}
\end{multienumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Similar issue to using tabular, any time you have to manually define the columns you make it very difficult to add items and keep the same structure. For example, my list is ordered,  1 through n. Multicols keys the order by columns. Your method may BUT if you decide to add an element the ordering will be all wrong unless you change every element. It ends up being a HUGE mess

Comment: The first method fixes the white-space and uses a list. You need to redefine your description list to suit (check on of the list packages such as enumitem).

Comment: I still get the same problem with trivlist.